# SDL_Jostick is sending weird ints

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, joystick

I'm having some issues trying to use SDL (version 2.0.3) for handling multiple game controllers in a SDL/OpenGL/C++ program.

I'm updating events using a SDL_PollEvent(&m_events) loop and looking for SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN (or SDL_JOYBUTTONUP/SDL_JOYAXISMOTION/SDL_HATMOTION) events with switch(m_events.type). 
What I want is to use the values of m_events.jbutton.which and m_events.jbutton.button (or the equivalents for axes and hat) to update arrays containing the state of my controllers.

I'm using Windows 7 Pro 64bit and Code::Blocks 13.12 though it's not supposed to change anything.

Here is my (debug) code, I tried to keep just the relevant parts :

main.cpp

```
#include "SceneOpenGL.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  SceneOpenGL scene(/* some args for window size */);

  if(!scene.initWindow())
    return -1;

  scene.mainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

SceneOpenGL.h

```
#ifndef SCENEOPENGL_H_INCLUDED
#define SCENEOPENGL_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include "Input.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class SceneOpenGL
{
public:
  SceneOpenGL(/* some args for window size */);
  ~SceneOpenGL();
  bool initWindow();
  void mainLoop();

private:
  SDL_Window* m_window;
  SDL_Event m_event;
  Input m_input;
  bool m_useJoysticks;
};
#endif
```

SceneOpenGL.cpp

```
SceneOpenGL::SceneOpenGL(/* some args for window size */) :
  m_window(0), m_input()
{
  if(SDL_NumJoysticks())
    m_useJoysticks = true;
}

bool SceneOpenGL::initWindow()
{
  if(SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK ) == -1)
  {
    std::cout << "Error while initializing SDL : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();
    return false;
  }
  /*
  **** Creation of SDL Window and GLContext ****
  */
  return true;
}

void SceneOpenGL::mainLoop()
{
  if(m_useJoysticks)
  {
    m_input.openJoysticks();
    SDL_JoystickEventState(SDL_ENABLE);
  }

  while(!m_input.terminate()) // m_input.terminate() sends true when SDL receives SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE event
  {
    m_input.updateEvents(); // this is the other loop where I update the joystick, keyboard & mouse state

    /* ...
    **** moving opengl objects & render ****
    */
  }
}
```

Input.h

```
#ifndef INPUT_H_INCLUDED
#define INPUT_H_INCLUDED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

class Input
{
public:
  Input();
  ~Input();
  void updateEvents();
  bool terminate() const;

  void openJoysticks();

private:
  SDL_Event m_events;

  int m_numJoysticks;
  SDL_Joysticks* m_joysticks[4]; // Array containing the first 4 joysicks

  bool m_terminate; // used for ending program
};
```

Input.cpp

```
#include "Input.h"

Input::Input() :
  m_numJoysticks(0), m_terminate(false)
{}

Input::~Input()
{
  for(int i(0); i < SDL_NumJoysticks(); i++)
    SDL_JoystickClose(m_joysticks[i]); // Closes joysticks before exiting
}

void Input::openJoysticks()
{
  m_numJoysticks = SDL_NumJoysticks; // Counts the connected joysticks
  if(m_numJoysticks > 4)
    m_numJoysticks = 4; // Sets maximum joysticks to 4

  for(int i(0); i < m_numJoysticks; i++)
  {
    m_joysticks[i] = SDL_JoystickOpen(0) // Open existing joysticks
    std::cout << "Joystick #" << i << " OK" << std::endl;
  }
}

void Input::updateEvents()
{
  while(SDL_PollEvent(&m_events))
  {
    switch(m_events.type)
    {
    /* ... Keyboard and mouse events, no problem there */
    case SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN:
      std::cout << "JOYBUTTONDOWN" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "type : " << m_events.jbutton.type << std::endl;
      std::cout << "which : " << m_events.jbutton.which << std::endl;
      std::cout << "button : " << m_events.jbutton.button << std::endl;
      std::cout << "state : " << m_events.jbutton.state << std:: endl << std::endl;
      break;

    /* ... Same thing for SDL_JOYBUTTONUP, SDL_JOYAXISMOTION, SDL_JOYHATMOTION  */

    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
      if(m_events.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)
        m_terminate = true; // end program
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}

bool Input::terminate() const
{
  return m_terminate;
}
```

And so here is the console output when I press A, B, X, Y on my x360 controller (= buttons 0, 1, 2 & 3) :

```
Joystick #0 OK
JOYBUTTONDOWN
type : 1539
which : 65536
button : §
state : Ý

JOYBUTTONDOWN
type : 1539
which : 1996554496
button :
state :

JOYBUTTONDOWN
type : 1539
which : 1996554752
button :
state :

JOYBUTTONDOWN
type : 1539
which : 1996555008
button :
state :

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 7.437 s
Press any key to continue.
```

As you can see it doesn't seem really OK. I even sometimes get different values for the same input (like here with the first button pressed), but I noticed that the difference between "which" values is 256 so it's not totally random. And the values are mostly the same if I restart the program or press the same button twice.
Well it seems like "event.jbutton.which" contains the informations of the button index (which is supposed to be a Uint8)

I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or if it's a bug in SDL2.

Comment: does it work on another platform? have you tried the latest hg source?

Comment: it seems there was indeed a problem with the sources, so the problem comes from my installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers appear to be the bitwise OR of a variety of flag fields, possibly with a value field.

Examining them in hex will make this obvious:

```
1996554752 = 0x77010200

1996554496 = 0x77010100

1996555008 = 0x77010300
```

It looks like your "button number" might be in bits 15-8, ie, the values 2, 1, 3

This is almost surely covered in the appropriate documentation

Comment: well the documentation says that the SDL_JoyButtonEvent which field should be a SDLJoystickID, whereas the button value should be a Uint8 stored in a different field (i.e event.jbutton.button)

Comment: My point is that the "which" may itself have sub-fields where different bits have different purpose.  Or you could have an incompatibility between the actual library and your header, such as different struct packing.

Comment: The second guess was indeed correct (incompatibility between header and library). I reinstalled the 2.0 version of the library (which I used before 2.0.3) and it now seem to work (I have to further test it though). I might have done something wrong when updating the library at some point.